# Create a function in C

Tags: c

Write a program that prompts the user to enter in two `long` values. Implements a function called `negative_count()` that takes two arguments of data type `long` and returns an integer that is the number of arguments that were negative. The function `main()` then displays the result.
For example:

Enter two integers of data type "long": -1264364007 -2012334695
Number of negative number entered 2

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

 /*
 * 
 */
 long num1,num2;
 void Negative_Count(long int,long int);
  int main(void) {


     printf("Enter two number: ");
     scanf("%ld%ld",&num1,num2);
     ("you entered %ld%ld",&num1,&num2);

     Negative_Count(num1,num2);


    return (0);
}

 void Negative_Count(long int num1,long int num2)
 {
       if (num1,num2<0)      
       printf("%ld%ld is negative.",&num1,&num2);
    else if (num1,num2>0)   
      printf("%ld%ld is positive.",&num1,&num2);
    else if (num1>0, num2<0)
            printf("%ld is negative",&num2);
    else if (num1<0, num2>0)
        printf("%ld is negative",&num1);
 }
```

Can I use a loop with two variables?

Comment: `if (num1,num2<0) `...i don't know what is this, but definitely not `C`.

Comment: did you miss a _whole_ `printf` before `("you entered %ld%ld",&num1,&num2);`?? Do you know the syntax for `printf()`;?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ***scanf*** and ***printf*** formatting had issues. Also the conditional check in the if statements were also wrong.

You can modify the code as below for proper working...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

 void Negative_Count(long int,long int);

  int main(void) {

    long num1,num2;

    printf("Enter two number: ");
    scanf("%ld%ld",&num1,&num2);
    printf("you entered %ld%ld \n",num1,num2);

    Negative_Count(num1,num2);

    return 0;

}

 void Negative_Count(long int num1,long int num2)
 {
       if (num1<0 && num2<0) {     
        printf("%ld , %ld are negative.",num1,num2);
       }
       else if (num1>0 && num2>0) { 
        printf("%ld , %ld are positive.",num1,num2);
       }
       else if (num1>0 && num2<0){
        printf("%ld is negative",num2);
       }
       else if (num1<0 && num2>0){
        printf("%ld is negative",num1);
       }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
scanf("%ld%ld",&num1,num2);
```

should be

```
scanf("%ld%ld", &num1, &num2);
```

---

```
("you entered %ld%ld",&num1,&num2);
```

should be

```
printf("you entered %ld %ld", num1, num2);
```

---

```
  if (num1,num2<0)      
   printf("%ld%ld is negative.",&num1,&num2);
else if (num1,num2>0)   
  printf("%ld%ld is positive.",&num1,&num2);
else if (num1>0, num2<0)
        printf("%ld is negative",&num2);
else if (num1<0, num2>0)
    printf("%ld is negative",&num1);
```

should be

```
if (num1 < 0 && num2 < 0)   
    printf("%ld and %ld are negative.", num1, num2);
else if (num1 > 0 && num2 > 0)   
    printf("%ld and %ld are positive.", num1, num2);
else if (num1 > 0 && num2 < 0)
    printf("%ld is negative", num2);
else if (num1 < 0 && num2 > 0)
    printf("%ld is negative", num1);
```

Use the ***and*** operator (`&&`): If both the operands are non-zero, then condition becomes true.

And note that `printf` (as opposed to `scanf`) doesn't need the address of the variable, just pass the value.

Comment: It keeps giving me the warning "Negative_Count.c:28:25: warning: format specifies type 'long *' but the argument has type 'long' [-Wformat]"